# How to Prove Pappus' Theorem

Tags: geometry

Points $A_1, B_1, C_1$ are taken on one line and points $A_2, B_2, C_2$ are taken on another line. The intersection points of lines $A_1B_2$ with $A_2B_1$, $B_1C_2$ with $B_2C_1$, and $C_1A_2$ with $C_2A_1$ are C, A, and B, respectively. Prove that points A, B, and C lie on one line.

I have no  idea where to even start this problem!! We are told to use Menelaus' theorem to solve this proof. [image]

Comment: If you Google "pappus theorem proof" the first hit is a PDF which says it has nine proofs and the fourth is a YouTube video.  Why not see if any of these help?

Comment: Can you solve it with the additional assumption that the given lines are parallel? If so, you are done, since we are free to assume it through projective transformations.

Answer (score 2):

I will outiline a proof using [trilinear coordinates](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrilinearCoordinates.html). Assuming that $P$ is the intersection of the given lines, we may take $PC_1 C_2$ as a reference triangle and state that
$$ C_1=[0;1;0],\quad C_2=[0;0;1] $$
$$ B_1=[1;x;0],\quad B_2=[1;0;y] $$
$$ A_1=[1;z;0],\quad A_2=[1;0;w] $$
Let us find the trilinear coordinates of $A_1 B_2\cap A_2 B_1$: they are given by $ [xy-zw; xyz-xzw; xyw-yzw] $. The trilinear coordinates of $A_1 C_2\cap A_2 C_1$ are given by $[1;z;w]$. The trilinear coordinates of $B_1 C_2\cap B_2 C_1$ are so given by $[1;x;y]$ and the wanted collinearity is equivalent to
$$ \det\begin{pmatrix}xy-zw & xyz-xzw & xyw-yzw \\ 1 & z & w \\ 1 & x & y\end{pmatrix}=0 $$
or to:
$$ \det\begin{pmatrix}xy & xyz& xyw\\ 1 & z & w \\ 1 & x & y\end{pmatrix}=xy\det\begin{pmatrix}1 & z& w\\ 1 & z & w \\ 1 & x & y\end{pmatrix}=0 $$
that is trivial (the last matrix has two equal rows).